# Count by month returning a string with 13 values

Tags: php, mysql, count

Sql query designed to output a string of totals per month is outputting 13 values (month 0?)

What do I need to add to the code to start counting at month 1 (January) and not month 0?

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(SightingDate) AS month, COUNT(CASE WHEN SpeciesName = 'Choreutis pariana' and Notes LIKE '%Adult%'  THEN 1 END) cnt
        FROM GAINLP 
        GROUP BY MONTH(SightingDate);";
if ($result3=mysqli_query($connect,$sql)) {
    while($row=$result3->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['cnt'] . ',';
    }
}
?>
```

The database contains one record for August.  I am expecting result of (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0) < 12 comma separated values.

Instead, above code outputs (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0) <13 CSV

Comment: I would imagine you have some rows in your database that have either invalid dates or `NULL` SightingDate so `MONTH` is returning `0` or `NULL`. Try `SELECT * FROM GAINLP WHERE MONTH(SightingDate) NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 12` to see where they are.

Comment: The above example actually contains only one row, and it does have a valid date.  The query, for whatever reason, is adding a leading zero to every string.

Comment: The rows you get in your output are not dependent on the `SpeciesName` value, they are dependent on **all** the `SightingDate` values in the table. Did you run the query I suggested?

Comment: You nailed it. Unknown to me, my partner entered a record with an unknown date, and mysql returned 00-00-0000, which as you pointed out, took down every query for the entire table.  I bow to you, wise one.

Comment: No bowing required! Since that was the problem, I'll post it as an answer as it could be useful to others.

Comment: Please do.  I had no idea that one null record could take down the entire table like that.  Now we know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you have some rows in your database that have either invalid or `NULL` `SightingDate` values, so `MONTH(SightingDate)` is returning `0` or `NULL`, thus giving you 13 rows in the output (1 to 12 for January to December plus 0/NULL). You can run this query to find the bad dates:

```
SELECT * FROM GAINLP WHERE MONTH(SightingDate) NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 12
```